# No property found for type after adding EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor to repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I have an entity with a relation to another one:

```
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
    private Boolean deleted = false;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "feature_assignment", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id"))
    private List<MyEntityFeature> myEntityFeatures;
```

and I have a perfectly working repository:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, UUID>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {
Optional<MyEntity> findByIdAndDeletedIsFalse(UUID id);
}
```

But when I extend EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor in my repository, it seems like it can't recognize former repository methods without entity graphs, even though the repository is still implementing the findById method. I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository.EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor.findOne(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.domain.EntityGraph)! No property findOne found for type MyEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type MyEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml contains the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And how can I fix this error? Is it mandatory to override the findOne method after implementing EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it by adding factory to Jpa Repositories:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EntityGraphJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```